# Understanding a problem

Tags: linear-algebra, learning

Note that these from linear algebra notes.

İt was defined fields, showed $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. Then,  below-mentioned qustion was proved. Yet, I didn't ask what happened. Can you explain? What deoes this question question?

Question: Find $a^ı, b^ı$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\dfrac {1} {a+b\sqrt {2}}= a^ı+b^ı\sqrt {2}$.

Comment: Put $(a+b\sqrt 2)(c+d\sqrt 2)=1$. Expand and equate the co-efficient of $\sqrt 2$ to $0$. The point is that $\{a+b\sqrt 2: a,b\in Q\}$ contains its multiplicative inverses. It's a field.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: It asks about the inverse of $a + b \sqrt2$ in the new field extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2$). Just multiply and divide $\frac{1}{a + b \sqrt2}$ by $a-b\sqrt2$ and you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about field extensions. The idea is basically that we can think of adding $\sqrt{2}$ to the rationals in a consistent way. You can then show that {1,$\sqrt{2}$} is a basis for this new field *when considered as a vector space over the rationals*. So what is being asked is to find the coefficients of 1 and $\sqrt{2}$ such that they equal the inverse of $a + b\sqrt{2}$ for some fixed a and b in the rationals. Both these new coefficients should be rational numbers. This can be done pretty mechanically by finding some basic relationships between the elements of your new field.

Hint: Since $\sqrt{2}$ satisfies a quadratic polynomial over the rationals, I suggest you might see whether every element of your new field does, too. That'll give you a handle on what things need to look like.

Does that help?

Comment: Glad to hear it. Field extensions and linear algebra are fun, enjoy it.